# Passing arguments through pointers

Tags: c

My problem here is that when "parr" prints, 'm getting zero instead of the content of "arrival_time".
Help Please.

```
void find_closest_flight(int desired_time, int *departure_time, int *arrival_time)
{
.......
    if (arr_time[i]-desired_time<=abs(temp))
    {
        .....
        *arrival_time=arr_time[i];
        ......
    }
    ......

  }
}

void main()
{
int hr=0; int min=0; int num; int arr=0; int depar=0;
    int *parr = &arr;
    int *pdepar = &depar;

......

num= hr * 60 + min;

find_closest_flight(num, parr, pdepar);

printf("%d", parr);
system ("pause");

}
```

Comment: 1) add a \n to your format string, or the output will not be flushed. 2) main() should return int.

Comment: You are indexing into an "array" that can hold only one element (you are pointing it at an int...).

Comment: You're trying to print a *pointer* using `%d`. That is undefined behaviour.

Comment: What would you suggest I do @DCoder

Comment: @wildplasser I tried that but no fix still

Comment: It was a comment, not a solution. Please read the other comments: there is no array in the entire source code, only pointers (which are pointing to single ints).

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a pointer to value instead of value to `printf`:

```
printf("%d\n", *parr);
```